# place a caption below a image in bootstrap tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have setup a tabs section on my website all works fine. The issue is with the caption it will not sit below the image. Here is the snippet of code and an image so you can see the issue.

[image: screenshot]

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">

<!--- Tabs Navagation
---------------------------->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
 <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Cities</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Education</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Restaurants</a></li>
</ul>

<!--- Tab Sections
---------------------------->
<div class="tab-content">

 <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
   <div class="thumb-caption">
    <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Belo Horizonte.jpg" alt="..."></a>
    <caption align="bottom">Belo Horizonte</caption>
   </div>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Brasília (2).JPG" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Cuiabá (2).JPG" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Curitiba.jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Fernando de Noronha_2.jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Fortaleza (1).jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Iguazu Falls.jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/IlhaGrande_Praia Lopes Mendes.jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Manaus- Amazonas.jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Natal (3).jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Porto Alegre (3).jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Recife Antigo.jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Rio de Janeiro.jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/Salvador 3.jpg" alt="..."></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="app/img/tabs/sao pablo.jpg" alt="..."></a>
  </div>

 <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
   <img src="">  
 </div>

 <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
   <p>this is text of tab 3</p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
   </div>
```

and CSS:

```
.tab-pane img {
max-width: 100px;
height: 100px;
padding: 10px;
float: left;
opacity: 1.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tab-pane img:hover {
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */

 }
```

So if you guys could help me that would be great as i been scratching my head for ages with this and i know its staring me right in the face.

Comment: Don't float the image....?

Comment: that just pulls the image out of place within the tabs section and text is on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you test

`.thumb-caption {
    border: 1px solid red;
}`

you will see why caption behaves as it does. It has plenty of space next to a floating img.

Would something like

`.thumb-caption {
    width: 120px;
}`

work?

You might also want to consider framing each `<img>` within a `<div class≈"thumb-caption>` so that everything lines up properly.

Comment: Of course, if you're going to have a caption for each img, then you're probably going to float the divs, not imgs.